# Properties of Wasserstein metric

Tags: probability, metric-spaces

Define the Wasserstein metric for two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ as follows:
$$
d_W(\mu,\nu)=sup_h\Big[\Big|\int h(x)\mu (x)-\int h(x)\nu (x): h(\cdot) \mathrm{\;is\;}1\mathrm{-Lipschitz\;continuous}\Big|\Big]
.$$

Suppose  $g(x)$ is $\epsilon$-Lipschitz continuous, do we have 
$$\Big|\int g(x)\mu (x)-\int g(x)\nu (x)\Big|\leq \epsilon \cdot d_W(\mu,\nu)$$

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $\epsilon$-Lipshitz continuous $g$, we have $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq \epsilon|x-y|$ so if you define $g'=g/\epsilon$ then $g'$ is $1-$Lipshitz continuous.

Therefore, $|\int g'd\mu-\int g'd\nu|\leq \sup_{h:\text{h is 1-Lipshitz}}|\int hd\mu-hd\nu|=d_W(\mu,\nu)$

Therefore, $|\int gd\mu-\int gd\nu|\leq \epsilon d_W(\mu,\nu)$

Answer (score 0):

hint: consider new function $g'(x) = g(x)/\epsilon$, which is $1$-Lipschitz continuous.